# How to convert array into specif object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert this array:

```
Array = [
  0: 0
  1: 25
  2: 50
  3: 75
  4: 100
]
```

into this object:

```
let disabilityOptions = [
    { key: 0, text: '0%', value: 0 },
    { key: 1, text: '25%', value: 25 },
    { key: 2, text: '50%', value: 50 },
    { key: 3, text: '75%', value: 75 },
    { key: 4, text: '100%', value: 100 },
  ]
```

I didn't succed to find some functions in lodash for this convert case.

Any advice or tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using `map` method.

```js
const data = [0 ,25 ,50 ,75 ,100]
const result = data.map((value, key) => ({value, key, text: `${value}%`}))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: hvala shone. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr=[
  0,25,50,75,100
];
/*0: 0
  1: 25
  2: 50
  3: 75
  4: 100*/
var disabilityOptions=[];

arr.forEach((key,val)=>{
    disabilityOptions.push({key: key, text: val+'%', value: val });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.map()` for that:

```js
var Array = [0, 25, 50, 75, 100];
var disabilityOptions = Array.map(function(item, index){
  return { key: index, text: item + '%', value: item };
});
console.log(disabilityOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy, use array map:

```
let origin = [0,25,50,75,100];

origin = origin.map(
  (value, key) => ({
    text: `${value}%`,
    value,
    key
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function to go over an array and create a new array with modified items.

```
var oldArray = [ 0, 25, 50, 75, 100];
var newArray = oldArray.map(function(item, index){
    return {key:index, value: item, text:item+'%'}
})
```